# Replace #NUM! result with a blank

Tags: excel-2007

I want to replace a #NUM! result with a blank

if {=SUM(LARGE(C2:I2,{1;2;3;4}))} returns a #NUM! (because 4 or more cells are blank) how do I replace the #NUM! with a BLANK?

the reason for this is because i would like to RANK the cells that contain a numeric value

eg: in the cell K2: =RANK(J2,$J2:J52,0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to complete you array formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(COUNTA(C2:I2)<2;0;LARGE(C2:I2,{1;2;3;4})))}
```

You can adjust the "2" depending on the number of values you want to have for `LARGE` to work.